# "cannot execute binary file" on aws ec2 with sage (using python) shell

Tags: python, shell, amazon-ec2, binaryfiles, sage

I would like to use SageMath (using Python) on an Amazon Web Services (AWS) EC2 instance.  For some instances, it works well, but for some others when I tried the SageMath console interface I got the following error:

```
/opt/sagemath-8.8/local/bin/python: /opt/sagemath-8.8/local/bin/python: cannot execute binary file
/bin/bash: Exit 126.
```

And with the SageMath shell environment, I got the same error:

```
(sage-sh) Administrator@EC2AMAZ-P55TVFN:~$ sage
/opt/sagemath-8.8/local/bin/python: /opt/sagemath-8.8/local/bin/python: cannot execute binary file
```

Same problem with python (on this instance):

```
(sage-sh) Administrator@EC2AMAZ-7G39AK9:~$ python bash: /opt/sagemath-8.8/local/bin/python: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error.
```

**Question**: How to solve this problem?

If useful, here is what $PATH command gives:

```
(sage-sh) Administrator@EC2AMAZ-P55TVFN:~$ $PATH
bash: /opt/sagemath-8.8/local/lib/R/lib:/opt/sagemath-8.8/local/lib:/opt/sagemath-8.8/build/bin:/opt/sagemath-8.8/src/bin:/opt/sagemath-8.8/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory
```

Now, on my laptop where SageMath is working well $PATH is as follows:

```
(sage-sh) Sébastien Palcoux@LAPTOP-7O5QV19T:~$ $PATH
bash: /opt/sagemath-8.7/local/lib/R/lib:/opt/sagemath-8.7/local/lib:/opt/sagemath-8.7/local/libexec/ccache:/opt/sagemath-8.7/build/bin:/opt/sagemath-8.7/src/bin:/opt/sagemath-8.7/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory
```

Comment: crossed https://superuser.com/q/1486999/308764

Comment: I think you will want to ask on http://ask.sagemath.org, because it is likely that there are some deeper things going on here than a typical Sage user can answer.  Are you trying to use the Cygwin version of Sage on a Linux system, for instance?

Comment: @kcrisman: I tried to post it on ask.sagemath but I cannot, I got the following error message `Internal server error
system error log is recorded, error will be fixed as soon as possible
please report the error to the site administrators`

Comment: I've contacted the admins, though I don't see any obvious problems.  You do have to create an account to post there.  You can also use the sage-support Google group which should have pretty active responses.

Comment: @kcrisman: I have an account there. The problem could come from the fact that I am in China. But I also tried from AWS EC2 (so virtually in USA) but same problem with ask.sagemath.

Comment: Huh.  Well, hopefully one of the (more knowledgeable than myself) admins will be able to take a look - I don't have access to the logs.  Emailing the group should be a good workaround for now.